# How should I structure these projects in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a template written in TeX from which I start most of the documents I write, consisting of a few .tex files and some other auxiliary files too.

I'd like this template and any downstream documents each to have their own (bare) repositories kept on a server, but changes will have to be merged to and from the template repository from the downstream ones. For example, I might want to modify the template and merge those changes into all of the documents I've created.

What's the best way to implement this kind of repository structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create a branch `template` where you could keep your template and then create other branches from it like `doc1`, `doc2`, then on any modification to the `template` you could easily merge it on `doc1` and `doc2` for example.

So here is the 'algorithm':

`git checkout template`

Hack the template...

`git checkout -b doc1` - create a doc starting off of `template`

Hack the doc...Oops, you discover something is wrong with the template

`git checkout template`

Fix it...

`git checkout doc1 && git merge template` - so you changed the template in doc1 and you can continue working at this document

Comment: This seems like a workable solution, thanks! I still wonder if there's any way of keeping separate bare/central repositories for each document, though?

Comment: Sure, multiple git repos with some remotes between them: http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html Then you'll have to work with projects as if they were branches (as explained above), instead of `checkout` you'll have to switch directories